# Angular2 components not binding the property to DOM

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am playing with Angular 2for learning.

I wrote a Tweet component where I am trying to show random picture, text and likes. Something like this:

**tweet.component.html**

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people?1" alt="">    
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <span>{{nameOfThePerson}}</span>
    <span> {{tweeterHandler}}</span>
    <span>{{tweetText}}</span>
    <heart [numberOfLikes]=5></heart>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am using it in `app.component.html` like this:

```
     <div>
         <tweet
            [nameOfThePerson]="randomName"
            [tweeterHandler]="handler1"
            [tweetText]="firstText">
         </tweet>
     </div>
```

On browser I am just getting the random image and number of likes, but not the text, name of the person and tweeter handler.

Please tell me what am I missing here?

Full code is here:

https://github.com/tsingh38/Angular2

Thanks.

Comment: did you define those variables as input in tweet.component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want to pass `randomName`, `handler1` and `firstText` as a string values to `tweet`'s properties, but what you are doing at the moment is passing the variables with those names as a values, the problem is they don't exist. If you want to pass `randomName`, `handler` and `firstText` as string values to `tweet`'s properties in your template, there are two ways to do this:

```
<tweet
    nameOfThePerson="randomName"
    tweeterHandler="handler1"
    tweetText="firstText">
</tweet>
```

Or:

```
<tweet
    [nameOfThePerson]="'randomName'"
    [tweeterHandler]="'handler1'"
    [tweetText]="'firstText'">
</tweet>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have'nt define  `randomName` etc in your app.component.ts file thts why browser is not displaying anything bind in this way instead

```
<tweet nameOfThePerson="randomName"
        tweeterHandler="handler1"
        tweetText="firstText"></tweet>
```